# Cave generator: flickering issue

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm creating this cave generator in GN. It generates a cave from a curve line. This curve line start and end points are based on the camera 'y' location.

[image]

The issue here is that the mesh flickers as the camera 'y' location changes... because it's generating the curve each time that value changes.

Is there any way to avoid this flickering? I know I could try creating a cylinder mesh and then deforming it along the curve but it's a little bit messy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by snapping camera position

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is this much more computationally expensive than deforming a cylinder along the curve? Thanks!